# How to save created markers from google.maps.event.addListener "click" using gmap4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I play around with google maps api using js but I don't how to save the markers position to database through ajax.

Does gmap4rails gem has easy way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing builtin as I don't see anything generic enough.

You'll have to handle this yourself:

- use the callback method to add the handler on the map
- if your map namespace is Gmaps.map, the map object itself is Gmaps.map.map (ugly I know)